# Switch case for displaying different OpenCV filters using console menu

Tags: c++, opencv, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a basic console menu using switch-case with C++. Said menu gives the option to select between different filters implemented using opencv. I'm fairly new to both opencv and C++, so I'm sure the code could be more efficent or nicely implemented.

Part of the code for the menu looks like:

```
void updateMenu(void){
cin >> opc;
switch (opc)
{
    case 1:
        cout << "Media \n";
        media(image, res1, 5);
        imshow("Media", res1);
        break;
```

While the main looks like:

```
int main(){
image = imread("image.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

menu();

while (open)
{
    updateMenu();
}

return 0;
}
```

menu() prints the options. open is a boolean defaulted to true that changes to false when 0 is pressed.

media is declared:

```
void media(Mat& imagen, Mat& returnMat, int var)
```

being the first Mat the source, the second one the destiny where the result will be saved to, and var the value for the median filter.

This code results in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpEr8.png). As seen, it displays a grey screen with nothing on it. If I change the main to contain only the code inside the main (shown below) the image will be filtered, resulting in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa1Wz.png).

```
int main()
{
image = imread("image.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

media(image, res1, 5);
imshow("Media", res1);
waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to understand what the error might be. No error messages are shown. Is there something wrong about using switch cases this way, or is there a more effective way of doing the same menu without switch?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I found my mistake. For anyone facing similar issues, all I had to do is turn the boolean *open* to false before the switch case, and turn it true again after.

Also, I had to create and later destroy a window:

```
        case 1:
        cout << "Media \n";
        media(image, aux, 5);
        hconcat(image, aux, res);
        namedWindow("Media", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("Media", res);
        waitKey(0);
        destroyWindow("Media");
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you want, or what problem you have, 
obviously your opc variable(you did not provide type of it in your code sample), after you entered its value and press enter, has no value 1 which is of type int, so code for 1 case, is not executed. When you call Media func directly with var=5, it all goes well, so clearly, case 1 is missed. 
Sometimes we did not entered value and pressed enter, when we have no clear console message what is expected to be done.

So, to be sure, what is happening, try to change your code to something like this

```
void updateMenu(void) {
cout << "please enter 1 for filter 5, or any other value and press enter\n";
cin >> opc; // we can suppose that opc is declared out side
switch (opc)
{
    case 1:
    cout << "Media \n";
    media(image, res1, 5);
    imshow("Media", res1);
    break;
```